# ngAnimate - Sliding both ways

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I'm struggling with an issue: I have a menu with x-amount of items.
In this example, I have three items.

Each item has a content section, so by clicking on the menu item, the content should slide in.

What I have achieved so far, is that when you're starting from "item 1" and changing to "item 2" will do the animation (sliding from right to left, like a powerpoint slide)

But I'd like the reverse effect as well, so it would slide from right to left when going from "item 2" to "item 1".
I just can't figure it out how to do this for both ways.

So what I'm asking for is some kind of carousel with ngAnimate, so I won't have to revert back to jQuery for these kind of animations. I'd like to cut out jQuery from my project while using AngularJS.

```js
console.clear();
var _app = angular.module("animate", ['ngAnimate']);

_app.directive("animate", [function() {
  return {
    scope: {},
    template: '<div class="header">' +
      '  <ul>' +
      '   <li data-ng-repeat="item in items" data-ng-click="move($index)">' +
      '    <div>{{item}}</div>' +
      '   </li>' +
      '  </ul>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="wrapper" style="position: relative; margin-top: 20px;">' +
      '  <div data-ng-if="index == 0" class="slide slide-left">Content 1</div>' +
      '  <div data-ng-if="index == 1" class="slide slide-left">Content 2</div>' +
      '  <div data-ng-if="index == 2" class="slide slide-left">Content 3</div>' +
      '</div>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
      scope.items = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]
      scope.index = 0;

      scope.move = function(index) {
        scope.index = index;
      }
    }
  }
}]);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: relative;
}

.header ul {
  padding: 0;
  height: inherit;
}

.header ul li {
  display: inline;
  width: 33%;
  height: inherit;
}

.header ul li div {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  text-align: center;
  height: inherit;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.slide {
  -webkit-transition: all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 2s;
  -moz-transition: all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 2s;
  -o-transition: all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 2s;
  transition: all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 2s;
  position: absolute;
}

.slide-left.ng-enter {
  left: 100%;
}

.slide-left.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  left: 0;
}

.slide-left.ng-leave {
  left: 0;
}

.slide-left.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  left: -100%;
}

.slide-right.ng-enter {
  left: -100%;
}

.slide-right.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  left: 0
}

.slide-right.ng-leave {
  left: 0;
}

.slide-right.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
<div ng-app="animate">
  <animate></animate>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to have a carousel effect, you need to switch the slide class based on the index you are transitioning to, so you use `ngClass` and change the class from `slide-left` to `slide-right` when moving to a lower index and vice-versa.

However, for the disappearing element the `ngIf` hides the element *before* the class is updated, so you need to delay the transitions to make sure `ngClass` is executed first. One way to do that is by using the `$timeout` function, which needs to be injected into your directive.

Your code becomes:

```
_app.directive("animate", ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
  return {
    scope: {},
    template: '<div class="header">' +
      '     <ul>' +
      '         <li data-ng-repeat="item in items" data-ng-click="move($index)">' +
      '             <div>{{item}}</div>' +
      '         </li>' +
      '     </ul>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="wrapper" style="position: relative; margin-top: 20px;">' +
      '     <div data-ng-if="index == 0" class="slide" ng-class="slideClass">Content 1</div>' +
      '     <div data-ng-if="index == 1" class="slide" ng-class="slideClass">Content 2</div>' +
      '     <div data-ng-if="index == 2" class="slide" ng-class="slideClass">Content 3</div>' +
      '</div>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
      scope.items = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]
      scope.index = 0;
      scope.slideClass = 'slide-left';

      scope.move = function(index) {
        scope.slideClass = index < scope.index
                         ? scope.slideClass = 'slide-right'
                         : scope.slideClass = 'slide-left';

        $timeout(function() {
          scope.index = index;
        });
      }
    }
  }
}]);
```

Check [this sample](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bqBvwp).

Also, if you already have [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap) you might want to try their carousel component.

Comment: Doesn't do what I expected :/ sliding from content 1 to content 2 goes from left to right, not really what a carousel would do. But I appreciate the answer, I'll have a look into the UI Bootstrap when I get the time to do so :)

Comment: @Jorrex please take a look at the edited answer, I guess it now works the way you wanted.

Comment: Yes! That's what I wanted. Thank you so much, I could not figure it out and got stuck on this for so long. Reading your code now, it seems so easy ..